# How to get the thumbnail image in full size?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having problem with the size of thumbnail.  Code I am using :

```
    wp_get_attachment_image_src( $v, array(200,200));
```

Need the actual size image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use :

```
 wp_get_attachment_image_src( $v, 'full' );
```

"$v" should be the attachment id.
Hope this will work for you.

Comment: you're the same person. @tri and Tristup are the same exact person. Are you kidding me? You created a duplicate account to build points?, [another question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26814986/2219158)

Answer (score 2):

passing second parameter as `full` will give you will original image.

```
  wp_get_attachment_image_src( $v, 'full');
```