# How to add a USER ROLE for user in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a user with a specific role of "Contributer". How to add this role into the wordpress admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to function.php to get this done :

```
 $result = add_role('contributor', __( 'Contributor' ), array('read'=> true,'edit_posts'   => false,'delete_posts' => false,'level_0' => 0));
```

Comment: I'm not sure how making `'edit_posts' => false` qualifies a [contributor role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor)...How can someone contribute, if they can't edit posts?

Comment: Hi Mervius, I have given a generalize syntax for adding the role only. Hope he/she can adjust the proper setting.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [Codex on the add_role() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) for more information. Usage is in the form of:

```
<?php add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities ); ?>
```

In the Codex, there's even an example for adding a basic contributor in the form of:

```
add_role(
    'basic_contributor',
    __( 'Basic Contributor' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
    )
);
```

Again...straight from the Codex.

Answer (score 1):

Searching on google a bit will give you.

### [Codex Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)

this will add new role

```
<?php add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities ); ?>
```

Give `role`, `display_name` whatever you want and `$capabilities` is an array of capabilities, you can find from above link.